# Nikon D5100 "Error Press Shutter Release Button Again"

Tags: nikon, camera, error

Whenever I turn on live view the shutter curtains/blades gets stuck, and I use the method show in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/3zlq4gObZ7A).

Which kind of fixes the problem temporarily but not fully, everytime I turn on Live View the shutter curtains/blades just keep getting stuck. I am only able to take pictures with this and I really want to take videos with it, Is there any permanent solution for this?

Also this camera is like 7+ years old